# Customize Search Results for Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, search

Is there a way to use a custom PHP template for search results of a custom post type. I know that you can have specific archive and category templates for custom post types. For example, archive-custom.php. But, the same doesn't work for search.php. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96388/27722) of yours, you can do the following inside your `search.php`:

```
if (isset($_GET['post_type']))
    get_template_part('search', $_GET['post_type']);
else
    // no post_type given
```

Then you have to set up the `search-{post_type}.php` files.

If you want to handle **only some** of the existing post types differently, do this by means of a `switch`:

```
$type = (isset($_GET['post_type'])) ? $_GET['post_type'] : '';
switch ($type) {
    case 'attorney':
    case 'criminal':
    case 'musician':
        get_template_part('search', $type);
        break;
    default:
        // default search stuff
}
```

Comment: Oh, glad I could help. Would you mind accepting this answer? Just click the check mark (upper left corner, below the vote counter)? This way other users can see this question has been solved and it won't get picked up by the Community bot.